# Weird Bugs using G++ compiler and QEMU emulator

Tags: c++, compilation, operating-system, g++, qemu

I am trying to write my own simple operating system in cpp and assembly using G++, NASM and LD. However, I encountered several odd bugs while emulating my operating system in QEMU.
For example, when I use a constant to index an array, the code executes perfectly.

```
#define VIDEO_MEMORY 0xB8000
#define COLUMNS 80
#define ROWS 25
#include "screen.h"
#include <stdint.h>

const char scancodes[] = {'\0','%','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0',
'-','=','~','\t','Q','W','E','R','T','Y','U','I','O','P','[',']','\e','\0','A', 'S','D',
'F','G','H','J','K','L',';','\0','`',
'\0','\\','Z','X','C','V','B','N','M',',','.',
'/','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0',
'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','-','\0','\0','\0','+','\0','\0','\0','\0','~',};


void main() {
    clear_screen();
    set_char_at_video_memory(scancodes[1], 0);

    while(1)
    {
        __asm__("hlt");
    }
}
```

[and here's the output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOvy0.png)

On the other hand, using a variable whose value is 1 doesn't work for some reason:

```
#define VIDEO_MEMORY 0xB8000
#define COLUMNS 80
#define ROWS 25
#include "screen.h"
#include <stdint.h>

const char scancodes[] = {'\0','%','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0',
'-','=','~','\t','Q','W','E','R','T','Y','U','I','O','P','[',']','\e','\0','A', 'S','D',
'F','G','H','J','K','L',';','\0','`',
'\0','\\','Z','X','C','V','B','N','M',',','.',
'/','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0',
'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','-','\0','\0','\0','+','\0','\0','\0','\0','~',};


void main() {
    clear_screen();
    int index = 1;
    set_char_at_video_memory(scancodes[index], 0);

    while(1)
    {
        __asm__("hlt");
    }
}
```

[and here's the output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEkjR.png)

I've been trying to solve this bug and similar ones for days to no success. If anyone could please help me out here, I would be really grateful!:)

Comment: Are you compiling this without optimisations? If so I would look at how your OS does stack memory.

Comment: Probably something is wrong with the functions you're not showing us. I would also look at the assembly difference.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. This is how I compile in in Make:
 g++ -m32 -ffreestanding -fno-pie -c -o $@ $<

Comment: That compiles without optimisations. In which case a local variable `index` will be allocated on the stack whereas a constant would not be. Therefore there must be something wrong with your stack memory , most probably in the linker script you did not show.

Comment: @Botje
ld -m elf_i386 -o $@ -Ttext 0x1000 $^ --oformat binary -nostdlib
this is the linker command
what do you think could go wrong?

Comment: @Botje I solved that problem by fixing the linker script, however, char pointers are still not supported, how can i improve my linker script:
ENTRY(main)
OUTPUT_FORMAT(binary)

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x1000; /* Set the starting address of the kernel */

    .text : { *(.text) } /* Code section */

    .rodata : { *(.rodata) } /* Read-only data section */

    .data : { *(.data) } /* Initialized data section */

    .bss : { *(.bss) } /* Uninitialized data section */

    /DISCARD/ : { *(.eh_frame) } /* Discard unnecessary sections */
}

Comment: Suggest you ask a new question with all components necessary for a [mre].